# Function seems to work within constant-space, but constant space is too much

Tags: haskell

I have the following function, which counts number of differences between two strings:

```
distance1 :: String -> String -> Int
distance1 list1 list2 = length . filter (uncurry (/=)) $ zip list1 list2
```

It works just fine. Can work on any size lists within constant space.

I also was playing around with - let's say - low level, recursion-based, not-good implementation for this function and had the following:

```
distance2 :: String -> String -> Int
distance2 list1 list2 = distanceHelper 0 0
 where
   distanceHelper index result
     | index == length list1 = result
     | otherwise = distanceHelper (index + 1) (result + diff)
     where
       char1 = list1 !! index
       char2 = list2 !! index
       diff = if char1 /= char2 then 1 else 0
```

I know accessing by index for linked list is terrible, but here I'm not worrying about time, but about space. Since it is tail recursive, I expect it also to run for any size list within constant space.

The following is the program used to test:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ distance2 list1 list2
  where
    list1 = replicate count 'A'
    list2 = replicate count 'B'
    count = 100000000
```

If I'll run the one with `distance1` and for any size (e.g. 100000000000000000), yes, it will be running for a very long time, but it will eat about 3-4 MB and do the job anyway.

If I'll run test with `distance2` (just with 100000000), it will immediately eat a lot of memory (about 1G), but then will stop eating memory and continue to do the job without consuming more memory. So it makes impression it also runs for constant space, but that space is too much.

I would like to understand why exactly the second version takes so much memory?

Note: just in case tried second version with bang patterns, i.e. declared inner function as `distanceHelper !index !result`, but that didn't help.

Comment: Do you get the same result when compiling with the `-O2` flag? It could also be a buffering issue, try to set `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering`.

Comment: @MikaelF, yes, exactly the same with `-O2` and with `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know accessing by index for linked list is terrible, but here I'm not worrying about time, but about space. Since it is tail recursive, I expect it also to run for any size list within constant space.

No, that's precisely the issue here.

If a list is generated with `replicate count 'A'`, it can be generated lazily. If we access the first element, discard it, then the second one, discard it, and so on, the computation can be performed in constant space, since elements can be garbage collected quickly after they are discarded. This requires the consumer to be something like

```
consume [] = ...
consume (x:xs) = .... (consume xs)   -- x was used and then discarded
```

If we instead use `!!` to access the list, the compiler can no longer discard the list elements. After all, we could later on request with `!!` an element we used a long time ago. Hence, the full list of `count` elements must be stored in memory.

Now, a very smart compiler might perform a static analysis and prove that the indices used in `!!` are strictly increasing, and we can indeed discard/garbage collect the prefix of the list. Most compilers are not that smart, though.

Further,  `length` is also used here:

```
 distanceHelper index result
     | index == length list1 = result
     ...
```

`length list1` will work in constant space if it can consume `list1`, i.e. if `list1` is no longer used afterwards. This is not the case, so that will force the full list to be generated and kept in memory, using `count` cells. Yet another reason why we should avoid `length` and `!!`.

To stress the point above:

```
let list = replicate count 'A'
in length list
```

should be constant space, while

```
let list = replicate count 'A'
in length list + length list
```

can not be (barring very smart optimizations), since we can not consume `list` for the first `length` call -- we need it for the second call later on.

Even more subtly,

```
let list () = replicate count 'A'
in length (list ()) + length (list ())
```

will work in constant space, since the result of function calls is not cached. Above, we generate (and consume) the list twice, and this can be done in constant space.

Comment: Why is the larger list using a smaller memory footprint then?

Comment: @MikaelF The OP is using a different, more efficient, function on the larger list, `distance1` instead of `distance2`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Could you please clarify that in the snippet `let list = replicate count 'A' in length list + length list` list will fully stay in memory, but still it will be list of thunks? Not the list with fully evaluated elements?

Comment: Is the non-strictness of the second argument also an issue? `result + diff` is building up a large thunk until it finally gets forced.

Comment: @chepner Indeed it is.

Comment: @xzt Yes, that's correct: `length` does not force the elements, so they will remain non evaluated (thunks).

Comment: Your tricky version at the end probably won't run in constant space with optimization.

Comment: @dfeuer With `-O2` I get 1.4MB for `count = 10^11`. Do you have some specific setting in mind?

Comment: @chi, I'm surprised! I'd have expected it to optimize to something like `let {foo = replicate count 'A'; list () = foo} in ...`, then inline `list` and end up with the same code as before. I wonder why that doesn't happen.